# Matlab Simulink generating no output

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am learning Matlab Simulink. Here is the basic simulation that I'm doing.

[image]

When I pressed `Start Simulation` I get these errors.

[image]

Then as suggested [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/9048-simulink-question) I changed my settings to this.

[image]

But now when I am simulating, a warning sound beeps but no error message is showing in Matlab `Command Window` and I am not getting my output.

Where is the problem and how can I solve it??

I am using Matlab 7.10.0(R2010a).

Comment: The beeping sound is just to signal the end of the simulation, it's not a warning. All is good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not getting any output in the Command Prompt because you haven't specified any sinks to export the data to the Workspace and so workspace variables aren't created.  You're only able to see the output in the Scope tool in Simulink but this data hasn't been exported to your workspace.  In Simulink, there is a `To Workspace` block that you can use to pipe the sinusoidal data to the workspace.  In the `Sinks` section of the `Library Browser`, choose the `To Workspace` block and connect the output of the `Sine Wave` black to this block... so:

[image]

[image]

To make things compatible, make sure you choose the option to output your data as an array format instead of time series... well I find that the array option is better.  Open up the `To Workspace` block and change the output to `Array`:

[image]

When you do this and run the simulation, you should see a variable called `simout` in your workspace that captures this data and `tout` that measures the time steps of each output amplitude in your sine data:

[image]

You can then plot the data by doing just `plot(tout, simout);`

[image]

## Minor Note

The "warning" beep happens because MATLAB is telling you that Simulink has finished the simulation.  Nothing wrong is happening.

Comment: I am not getting any output in the Scope tool in Simulink. Scope should show me a sinusoidal wave shape.

Comment: I'm getting an output. I'm not sure what's wrong. http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ovwzb.png - There's the output of my scope. *shrugs*.

Comment: That's the output I'm looking for. Could it be a software problem? Should I upgrade to a newer version??

Comment: @Scotia웃 I'm not sure if it's a software problem... I've used Simulink for older versions than R2010a and I see the output just fine.  There is an auto-scale button on the scope.  Did you try pressing that to see if something happens? The amplitude may be too small to visualize on the scope.  In my scope: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ovwzb.png, it is the button at the top in the middle that looks like a square with 4 arrows pointing at each corner.

Comment: @Scotia웃 Also, did you try exporting the data to your workspace like I did above and did you try manually plotting it?

Comment: Actually scope window iself is not opening after pressing `Start Simulation`. Just a warning beep every time. No scope window is showing. No i didn't try  exporting the data.

Comment: @Scotia웃 You need to open the scope window manually by double click. Then press the autoscale button. Also be aware that by default only the last 5000 datapoints are saved and shown, you can change that in the scope preferences. After all that it should work.

Comment: @rayryeng are you aware of the possibility of logging the signal directly? Instead of the `toWorkspace` block a little antenna is showing up on the signal. Under the hood happens the same, just without an additional block.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I didn't know that.  It shows you how much I use Simulink. Thanks!

Comment: @thewaywewalk, You saved my life! Yap, after double clicking over the scope icon I've got the scope output.

Comment: I actually thought that's what you were doing... Double clicking. I would have suggested that but there seems to have been a miscommunication. Oh well. Glad it works.